# SOQL Agregate result issue

Tags: apex, soql

I have a picklist in picklist_active_inactive__c with Values and Inactive Values.
The problem is given by I have to get by SOQL some values, and the picklist_active_inactive__c records have inactive an active values.

Example:

- Object: picklist_active_inactive__c
- Field: picklist__c
- Values of picklist__c

  - Active:

    - Values: value0
    - API Name: value01
  - Inactive:

    - Values: value0
    - API Name: value0

I need count picklist_active_inactive__c that have the *value0* value.

I tried

```
SELECT toLabel(picklist__c) a, count(ID) b
     FROM picklist_active_inactive__c
     WHERE toLabel(picklist__c) = 'value0'
     GROUP BY picklist__c
```

And it return *AggregateResult:{b=1, a=value0}, AggregateResult:{b=2, a=value0}*

I need only a record with *AggregateResult:{b=3, a=value0}*

GROUP BY toLabel(picklist__c) does not work, it said: *Only date aggregate functions are allowed as grouping expressions: toLabel*

EDITED:
I have code to aggregate the results in a map, that works. I only whant to know if it is posible to do it in only one SOQL query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `GROUP BY picklist__c`, the grouping that is being applied is on the API value of the picklist entry, rather than the label. That's why you end up with two `AggregateResults`. The database is actually storing the API values.

As you've observed, the `toLabel()` function isn't a legal grouping.

You can post-process these `AggregateResult` objects in Apex to check for duplicated labels. Something like this should work:

```
Map<String, Integer> valueCounts = new Map<String, Integer>();

for (AggregateResult a : listOfAggregateResults) {
    String picklistValue = a.get('a');
    String recordCount = a.get('b');

    if (valueCounts.containsKey(picklistValue) {
        valueCounts.put(picklistValue, valueCounts.get(picklistValue) + recordCount);
    } else {
        valueCounts.put(picklistValue, recordCount);
    }
```

Then `valueCounts` has your global total by picklist value.

Comment: Hello, i have a similar code that works. I only whant to know if it is posible to do it in only one SOQL query. Thanks

Comment: No, I don't believe it is possible in a single SOQL query. This would be helpful context to include in your question.